# Can I use Entity Framework objects outside database scope?

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I am designing a database for storing products and some properties belonging to them. The properties can be inherited from parent product to the child product. For example:

```
ProductA   ---> PropertyA, PropertyB
|-ProductB ---> PropertyC
```

In this example, ProductB should have PropertyA and PropertyB in addition to PropertyC. In order to get all the properties of a certain product, I need to go through all the parents and accumulate all the properties in a list. However, the Property class itself is a database entity, so can I use it to define normal objects (i.e. detached from database) without having them affecting the database contents, i.e. create, modify, delete instance as normal C# objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.  Entity Framework 4.0 onwards supports what is known as a POCO entity (Plain Old CLR Object).  They can exist entirely separately from your database concerns and when appropriate you can attach them to an instance of an Entity Framework Context for persistence to the database.

Likewise you can Detach entities from a Context having retrieved them from the database through the same Context should you choose to manipulate them within your Domain Model in such a way that you don't want them persisted again.

Depending on whether you're doing true Code First or Database First will determine the development workflow you use for creating these entities.